# MYSQL PHP Ordering

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
$date=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players where AdminLevel>='1' ORDER BY AdminLevel,UltReg DESC LIMIT 0,100");
```

I wanna sort something, and i don't know how to use for more "orders"

Comment: OK, so what's the question? What do you expect to see here? What do you actually see?

Comment: I wanna sort something, and i don't know how to use for more "orders"

Comment: What do you want to sort your orders by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional levels to the ORDER BY statement by adding them separated by commas, as you have done for two levels.

For example:

```
$date=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players where AdminLevel>='1' ORDER BY AdminLevel,UltReg DESC, anotherField ASC, yetAnotherField DESC, oneMoreFieldHere LIMIT 0,100");
```

Additionally, you should be using `mysqli_query()` instead of `mysql_query()` as `mysql_query()` [has been deprecated](http://ch2.php.net/mysql_query).